# C# append to file without "using" statement

Tags: c#, file, append

Let's suppose I get a lot of data (text) in a loop when my timer ticks and I want to write it all down (maybe even to several different files). That's why I want to keep my log file(s) open since I start my program. What classes (FileStream, StreamWriter) or what strategy should I use in this case? I don't ask for code, I just want some advice here. Thank you.

Comment: I would say : "dont reinvent the wheel". Make use of logging framework like nlog or log4net or another

Comment: Just open the file *outside* the loop.

Comment: [using directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx). I don't see what that has to do with loops or files. Did you perhaps mean [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)? When a language has two features that both involve the same keyword, it helps if you use the correct one. It helps even further if, if you're not using the official name, you at least avoid using the name of the *other* feature.

Answer (score 1):

Open your file outside of the loop and keep the stream open. If you want to close later on, you can call dispose.
The better idea to log is using a logging framework like log4net or any other you find.